# CSS based image preloader doesn't work

Tags: css, image

I wanted to create a preloader which would download all images before showing the website, but later I needed to switch from `<img>` to CSS-styled `ul`-s and after that it stopped working - browser doesn't wait for images to load.

HTML:

```
<head>
[...]
<ul id="imgPreLoader">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
</ul>
[...]
</head>
```

CSS :

```
#imgPreLoader {
display:none;
}

#imgPreLoader li:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url('...');
}

#imgPreLoader li:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url('...');

}

#imgPreLoader li:nth-child(3) {
background-image: url('...');

}

#imgPreLoader li:nth-child(4) {
background-image: url('...');

}
```

Comment: When you say "browser doesn't wait for images to load"... how do you know?  What exactly happens when you look at it or test it?  What do you think should happen?

Comment: With working preloader browser downloaded about 1.2MB of the website before displaying anything, now it loads only 400kB and the rest is loaded while browsing which doesn't look nice.

Comment: what JS do you use to detect when to remove display:none from #imgPreLoader?  Or maybe I am misunderstanding your question.  Can you post your site, or a stripped-down example?

Comment: http://folmert.info/importVital/ 
I never remove `display:none` from `#imgPreLoader` - instead I `show()` the `body` with jQuery after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because you have set `display:none`. I think many browsers will not load the background image if display is none even though they will load the source of a non-displayed img element.

Instead of setting `display:none`, try something like this:

```
#imgPreLoader {
   visibility:hidden;
   position:fixed;
}
```

This should accomplish the same thing in that it will prevent the elements from displaying and affecting the layout, but it should force the browser to load the background images.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate:
a) your <li> elements have no associated non-zero area, where the background image can be rolled out
b) you bound some necessary event handling code to the <img>, but not the <li> elements
etc.